# Compiling relic library (for msp430)

Tags: linux, cmake, msp430, contiki, relic

I'm trying to compile relic in order make some simulations on COOJA.
For your information I am using COOJA in a virtual machine ( Instant contiki 2.7 ), It comes with msp430-gcc-4.7.0
I ran the following commands ( according to the buildinstrtuctions)

```
 tar xzvf relic-0.3.5.tar.gz
 mkdir -p relic-target
 cd relic-target
 ../relic-0.3.5/preset/msp-pbc-80.sh ../relic-0.3.5
 make
```

When i try to make i get this error:

```
 user@instant-contiki:~/Desktop/relic/relic-target$ make
 [0%] Built target arith_objs
 [0%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/relic_s.dir/arch/relic_arch_msp.c.obj
 {standard input}: Assembler messages:
 {standard input}:76: Error: Missing symbol name in directive
 {standard input}:76: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `x' 
 .
 .
 .
 make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/relic_s.dir/arch/relic_arch_msp.c.obj] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/relic_s.dir/all] Error 2
 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can somebody please tell me how to fix this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Can somebody please explain this line
>
> "Run cmake inside the target directory, using one of the MSP430 presets (check the preset directory for available presets):"

The scripts in the preset folder call CMake for you with the appropriate configuration parameters.  You just need to choose the correct script corresponding to your hardware.

Comment: I ran this command from relic-target directory   ../relic-0.3.5/preset/msp-pbc-80.sh ../relic-0.3.5  , Is this what is needed ? What about the error in the snapshot?

Comment: According to the instructions, that command looks correct.  After you run the script, go to the relic-target directory and type `cmake-gui .` or `ccmake`.  Look through the entries and see if any entries show up as "NOT-FOUND" or blank.

Comment: No, I don t find any entries with Not-found or blank

Comment: Anyway, a friend managed to compile it on a native machine using msp430-gcc-4.6, I will test it later.

Comment: @jmstoker did you solve the problem? I am having the same issue. Any help is appreciated.